# Nodejs Express hbs: css MIMETYPE turns into text/html

Tags: node.js, express

I know this question has been asked many times before but I have tried all the solutions and I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
My server.js file:

```
  const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const routes = require('./routes.js');
const hbs = require('hbs');


let app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

routes(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Started up at port ${port}`);
});
```

My routes.js file:

```
module.exports = (app) => {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    app.get('/accounts', (req, res) => {        
       res.render('manage_accounts.hbs');
    });
};
```

My css link in manage_accounts.hbs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Note that I have tries using "/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" as href and it turns to *"http://localhost:3000/accounts/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"* which still doesn't work.

My folder structure:

```
/project
  /server
    server.js
    routes.js
  /views
    manage_accounts.js
  /public
    plugins/
       plugin/
          plugin.css
```

Error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case I am loading two stylesheet files in the `head` element, the first of which is not served (actually a 404) but in Chrome manifests as a 'Refused to apply style because MIME type' error. Try in Firefox, does the file even actually load?

Comment: @Brendan No. It returns 404

Comment: Yah so the problem is likely that Express `static` is sometimes failing to serve multiple files at once for some reason, even when they are in the same directory and can be loaded individually - bug? Do you have other stylesheets loading in the head successfully or just one? For reference I am running Express 4.16.2 on OSX. My path has no spaces in the name (which some people attributed to a similar problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem was with path. After some googling I found out the solution:
I should use **path** module which is built-in in nodejs in order to set the path of my public folder. Because the server.js file is not on the root directory and so the path gets messed up.
The new middleware is something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see font awesome css in your folder structure. Either you path is incorrect or you don't have copy of font-awesome. This should be fixed.
OR
You can use CDN version of the file, something like
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

source: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: I used plugin.js as an example of how my plugins are place in my folder hierarchy. One can be font-awsome

Comment: So in that case, It is certain that path is messed up somewhere, Can you just open up that path in browser and check
1. If contents of CSS is not served - definited path is wrong, check what localhost:3000/public points to which directory. In Addition also check for space in path.
2. If contents of CSS is served, check the network request for content-type is it serving.